# Channel receive from just a Println in go routine throws deadlock exception

Tags: go

I have some code where i am trying to print the content of a channel in a goroutine using fmt.Println. Here is the simplified version of code.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
  ch := make(chan int)
  go fmt.Println(<-ch);
  ch<- 10;
  time.Sleep(time.Second * 10);
}
```

When I run the above code I am getting this error.

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
        C:/cygwin64/home/vmadhusudana/go/channel.go:9 +0x67
exit status 2
```

However it works fine when I call fmt.Println from a function

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go func(){fmt.Println(<-ch)}();
    ch<- 10;
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 10);
}
```

What is making the difference here?

Comment: This is covered in the tour: [The evaluation of f, x, y, and z happens in the current goroutine and the execution of f happens in the new goroutine.](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first version, the channel read is performed from the main go-routine - hence the deadlock.
The second version, the read is done from the created go-routine.

Basically this:

```
go fmt.Println(<-ch);
```

becomes:

```
v := <-ch
go fmt.Println(v);
```

As the parameters to the function are evaluated *before* it's invocation.

P.S. The defer statement behaves similarly. So always use a closure if you want the value passed to a go-routine or defer statement to be evaluated at "runtime".

Answer (score 2):

```
// receive the value from channel firstly
// then create new goroutine to println
go fmt.Println(<-ch)

// receive channel in new goroutine 
go func(){fmt.Println(<-ch)}()
```

https://play.golang.org/p/xMyqd-Yr8_a

this will help you to understand the order of exec.